# .bootstrapMaterialDatePicker is not a function on Codeigniter 3

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter-3

I'm having the following problem in my form has two dates of type varchar

```
     <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 form-control-label">
          <label for="areareal_cadastro">Cadastrado em</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-7">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-line">
                    <input type="text" id="areareal_cadastro" name="areareal_cadastro" value="<?= $construct_areareal['areareal_cadastro']; ?>" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 form-control-label">
            <label for="areareal_atualizar">Atualizado em</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-7">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-line">
                    <input type="text" id="areareal_atualizar" name="areareal_atualizar" value="<?= $construct_areareal['areareal_atualizar']; ?>" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But in the console I get the following error, being that I'm not declaring this variable anywhere.

[image]

Comment: is the JQuery included before you try to use the datepicker js?

Answer (score 0):

try this js use library too.

```
$('#input_id').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({ weekStart : 0, time: false });
```

Answer (score -2):

You Have to add Below CSS and Javascript

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```